# JAXB/Jackson XML generic serialization

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jackson

I have a `Shape` class, and a `Circle` and `Square` subclasses. Then I have a `Container` class that has a `List<Shape> shapes` field.

I'm doing XML serialization with Jackson, and I'm getting

```
<shapes><shape radius=".."><shape w=".." h=".."></shapes>
```

...but what I really want is

```
<shapes><circle radius=".."><square w=".." h=".."></shapes>
```

I've tried annotating `shapes` with

```
@XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(type = Circle.class),
        @XmlElement(type = Square.class)
})
```

...but that just gives me

```
<shapes><shapes><Circle radius=".."></shapes><shapes><Square w=".." h=".."></shapes></shapes>
```

...so it's almost right, but those wrappers are annoying. Is there any way of getting what I want, even if it means changing my JAXB implementation?

Comment: One thing that may help in testing out approaches is to consider that Jackson XML module is designed for POJO->XML->POJO case, so it is easiest to start with Java objects, see what XML is produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options is to use [@XmlElementRef](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html) annotation. Excerpt from javadoc:

> This annotation dynamically associates an XML element name with the JavaBean property. When a JavaBean property is annotated with XmlElement, the XML element name is statically derived from the JavaBean property name. However, **when this annotation is used, the XML element name is derived from the instance of the type of the JavaBean property at runtime**.

So, you can do something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Container {
     //...

     //without XmlElementWrapper <shapes> element will be omitted
     @XmlElementWrapper(name="shapes")
     @XmlElementRef
     public List<Shape> getShape() {
          //your logic here
     }
}
```

Check out the constraints in javadoc. You might need to annotate `Shape`, `Circle` and `Square` with `@XmlRootElement` for this to work:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Circle {
    //no-arg constructor
    Circle() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I came here again to add that I found `XmlElementRef` to be the magic I needed, but you beat me to it! I didn't have to add the `XmlElementWrapper`, though ("<shapes>" is still there) but anyway, this is the right solution, thank you!

Comment: @EduGarcia I didn't notice that `<shapes>` is a root element here. You'll need wrapper if you want to use `<shapes>` as a child element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like [this](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html). I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for that! Unfortunately, that seems to add <shapes xsi:type="circle"...> instead of <circle ...>

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, as long as you make sure to indicate that type `Shape` is polymorphic, and that this type is to be preserved. In Jackson, you do this by adding `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation on `Shape` class. You may use "mix-in annotations", if you can not modify the class directly; or, if you prefer, add this annotation next to property of that type (if so, need to annotate all properties with that type).

This is the first step; and the other part is to use proper inclusion mechanism. Default is "as-property", which would add a new element, but what you want here is to include type as sort of fake key, using inclusion type of `WRAPPER_OBJECT`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
```

for JSON this would add a surrounding JSON Object; with XML that should result in name being used as element name.

One caveat is that support for polymorphic type inclusion is bit fragile, due to structural differences between XML and JSON. So I have not used approach described above with XML, just with JSON. But in theory it should work.